# COLLATE LOCALIZED not ignoring apostrophes

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, unicode

my problem is simple, the function "COLLATE LOCALIZED" used in my SQLite request won't ignore the apostrophe ( `'` : [UNICODE 27](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27)), while it does ignore the quotes ( `"` : [UNICODE 22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22)).

*Example :*

I get :

- **'dfg'**
- abc
- "hij"
- klm

instead of :

- abc
- **'dfg'**
- "hij"
- klm

Is it intended to ignore the apostrophe ? How can I sort it anyway ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `REPLACE` to remove/ignore `'` and `"` in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '''', ''),'"', '');
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0a28b/9/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════╗
║  col  ║
╠═══════╣
║ abc   ║
║ 'dfg' ║
║ "hij" ║
║ klm   ║
╚═══════╝
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but since I COLLATE, doesn't it slow down the request ?